# Check if recv is running

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, winsock

I have a server program which creates a new thread for each connection it accepts. The function called in this thread is always the same. It has an infinite `do...while` statement which replies to any data that is received. Also, I'm using blocking-mode sockets, so the fact that `recv` blocks the thread is expected and satisfactory.

My problem is that sometimes the main thread of the program needs to check the state of the connection of socket (or the network connection state).

I've read a lot on this problem and found nothing on blocking-mode sockets; but I found the issue for non-blocking sockets (using `recv` as stated below):

```
char buf;
int recResult=recv(sock,&buf,1,MSG_PEEK);
```

This function sends 1 byte of data and returns the value. By this value and `WSAGetLastError()` function we can check the state of the connection.

But I'm afraid that when I call function of checking the state of the socket, the `recv` function may be running on other thread. If I change socket blocking mode, it can return with bad value and 'set' its own value to `WSAGetLastError()` function.

**So my problem is how to check if `recv` is running on another thread.**

I've searched a lot, but found nothing. Also I haven't found if changing the blocking mode affects `recv` and if it 'sets' its own value for WSA error.

P.S.: Yes, I know I can check the result of `recv` on my thread, but I need to check if it is running from a different thread, not find its result.

Comment: What do you mean by "check if recv function is currently _running_ on other thread"? Do you want to check whether the thread is blocked and waiting for data? Or that the socket is not closed by remote side (i.e. connection is active) hence the other thread can expect more data to come?

Comment: If a hard socket error occurs, the recv() in the thread is going to see that (return value of 0 or -1).  If what you're really going after is assurance that the threads are talking to clients that haven't silently gone away (their computer shut down hard, a router somewhere in the middle died, etc), then setting keepalive is the best option.  That way, when the TCP stack sees that a connection isn't viable, the recv() call of the threads will see the error.  Look up setsockopt/SO_KEEPALIVE, as well as WSAIoctl/SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS (to make the alive check happen more often).

Comment: Use a mutex-protected variable. Set it to true before calling `recv` in the other thread, and clear it after `recv` returns.

Comment: Make the thread report its state, for example by setting a variable to "recv running".

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but in case you haven't considered it - having one thread per client connection is not going to scale well at all. Assuming you're on windows with the `WSAxxx` functions, consider using I/O completion ports instead of one blocking `recv` per thread. [Here is an in-depth example of using I/O completion ports with WinSock](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13382/A-simple-application-using-I-O-Completion-Ports-an)

Comment: XY problem. (1) Using MSG_PEEK does not change the blocking mode of the socket. (2) The main method doesn't need to call `recv()` to check the network state if something else is already calling `recv()`. The connection thread should maintain *data* about the state of its connection, and the main thread should check that data.

Comment: And if the reading thread *is* blocked in `recv()` there is nothing wrong with the connection anyway. It's when it gets an error from `recv()` that you have a problem. You're trying to get the API to do something it won't do.

Comment: @tomasz, yes I want to check if other thread is blocked and waiting for data. And yes, I want to check if socket on the remote side is not closed.

Comment: And, as I said, you can tell that via *data*. You don't need this MSG_PEEK solution.